# Is there a way to insert a particular sequence in the header and the footer of a csv, shifting the data of the dataframe one row down?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

[image: the result should be a csv having a sequence in the header and the footer]

I have tried writing the header and footer sequences with python excelwriter and then converting it to csv but it does not work. Can anyone suggest me a piece of code in python ?

Comment: Please, check [ask]. Post [mre] of your code, sample input and expected output. Please, don't post images of code, error, data, etc. copy/paste as formatted text. Right now it looks like you expect someone to write code for you. This is not how SO works.

Comment: Appologies, I'm a bit new here. Thanks for your inputs, will keep em in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your output file and simply write to it. Let pandas to_csv write to the open file object.

```py
with open("myoutput.csv", "w") as file:
   # output your first line
   print("1890000123", file=file)
   # continue to add the csv
   df.to_csv(file, ... other options here)
   print("178AD...", file=file)
```